# Neo4j export from Aura to AWS EC2 community instance corrupts database

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j

I'm moving a database from Neo4j AURA to a Neo4j community edition instance hosted in AWS EC2.

**The problem:**
I export one of the AURA snapshots, it downloads a `neo4j.dump` file. When using the next command on the EC2 instance to **import / load** the file `neo4j-admin database load --from-path=/root neo4j --overwrite-destination=true` the process is okay but after that, I can't connect to the database using the browser or any driver anymore, the browser connects via `bolt` but it gives me an error that *neo4j database is no available use command* `:sysinfo` *for more information*

[image]

Also when running `neo4j-admin database check neo4j`

Get:
[image]
[image]

**Notes:**

- I have repeated the process by creating new EC2 Neo4j instances and the result is the same, I also tried in the Enterprise edition with no luck
- If anyone is wondering why I'm moving from AURA, the reason is the latency/connection time, our server is in Heroku, and with aura, every query takes up to >300ms even just doing a simple MATCH, in the EC2 instance takes <10ms.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477398/database-neo4j-is-unavailable-cannot-reset-neo4j-database, especially answers from keithpjolley and ugurtosun.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was running the `neo4j-admin database load` command as `root`
**Solution:**

```
su neo4j             // this is the default user the ec2 neo4j template created for me
cd $HOME
wget "url to backup" // download of put .dump file here
pwd                  // To then add it the path of the neo4j load command
neo4j-admin database load --from-path=/var/lib/neo4j neo4j --overwrite-destination=true
```